# Tallying Results in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to tally results for a table. The results have replicated product numbers. Here is an example of the output:

```
1203202
1203207
1203205
1203226
1203226
1203226
1203193
1203218
1203213
1203213
1203161
1203161
1203217
1203217
1203217
1203217
1203237
1203206
1203212
1203212
1203212
```

So for example since `1203212` shows up three times, I need it to be displayed like this:

```
Product # 1203212 Count 3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a table `purchases` with a column `product_num`, try:

```
SELECT product_num, COUNT(*) FROM purchases GROUP BY product_num
```

That will give you output like this:

```
1203212 3
1203217 5
...
```

**EDIT:**
See what I mean **[HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a0a3/1)**